# Printing Date object without using format method

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am using `SimpleDateFormat` class to set pattern and using the `parse` method to parse the `String` to `Date` object.

But when I am printing the `Date` object without using method `format()`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
Date dat1 = format.parse("2017-11-01");
System.out.println(dat1);
```

My result is:

> Sun Dec 30 00:00:00 UTC 1990

Comment: I can't reproduce that - I get January 2nd 2017. But fundamentally you want `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`. When you have problems with `SimpleDateFormat`, the **first** thing to do is check your format string really, really carefully against the documentation. (Note that the problem isn't how the resulting `Date` is being formatted - it's the parsing.)

Comment: The good solution is to drop the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class and use `java.time`: `LocalDate.parse("2017-11-01")` will give you what you expect. The short-sighted solution is to use lowercase `yyyy` instead of uppercase in your format pattern string.

Comment: Thanks i got the my mistake resolved. I will try to user java.time.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2017-11-01" )
```

## Results not reproducible

Your results cannot be reproduced. See [code run live at IdeOne.com:](https://www.ideone.com/Q0XvyI)

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "YYYY-MM-dd" );
Date dat1 = format.parse( "2017-11-01" );
System.out.println( dat1 );
```

> Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2017

## java.time

You are using troublesome old legacy classes now supplanted by the java.time.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2017-11-01" )
```

> ld.toString(): 2017-11-01

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).