# parse date error in scala

Tags: scala, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a date in scala like below

```
scala> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

scala> import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Calendar

scala> val simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDD")
simpleDateFormat: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@1e3cd860

scala> val date = simpleDateFormat.parse("20180312")
date: java.util.Date = Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 PST 2017
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It’s not only long outdate (aloing with `Calendar` and `Date`), it is also notoriously troublesome. Instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java SimpleDateFormat always returning January for Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560279/java-simpledateformat-always-returning-january-for-month)

Comment: Another related question: [Printing Date object without using format method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477718/printing-date-object-without-using-format-method) (about formatting, not parsing, otherwise the problem is the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `yyyyMMdd`. Notice `MM` is in caps.

## Scala REPL

```
scala> val simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
simpleDateFormat: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@ef87e460

scala> val date = simpleDateFormat.parse("20180312")
date: java.util.Date = Mon Mar 12 00:00:00 EET 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you Java code trusting that you can translate to Scala:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20180312", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

> 2018-03-12

No need for the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class and its long outdated friends `Calendar` and `Date`. No need to specify a format pattern string yourself since the formatter you need is built-in. No way to get the case of format pattern letters wrong. java.time, the modern Java date and time API is giving you all this. I warmly recommend it. On top of this, the `LocalDate` class of java.time matches your need much more precisely than `Date` or `Calendar`: a `LocalDate` is a date without time-of-day.

### What went wrong in your code?

Uppercase `YYYY` in the format pattern string is for week-based year, the year that the week number of the week belongs to (so really only useful with week numbers). `MM` is fine for month. Uppercase `DD` is for the number of the day within the year (lowercase `dd` is for day of month). So you asked for the week-based year that began with week 1 of 2018, month of March and the 12th day of the year. This is self-contradictory. One of the troublesome traits of `SimpleDateFormat` is that where it ought to throw an exception with such impossible requirements, instead it pretends that all is well and gives you some incorrect result. Let me guess, your week begins on Sunday? So apparently it gave up on month and day-of-year (since it didn’t really know the calendar year) and just gave you the first day of week 1. On my computer I got Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2018, which probably is because Monday is the first day of the week here.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.